# Bind multiple Dropdowns and retrieve user selction at postback

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on an MVC Core form where a requester has to define some approvers for his application. When preparing the model for the Get request, I first get the roles for the approvers. Currently, there are always four roles returned:

1. Category Head
2. Governance Head
3. Concessions VP
4. Commercial EVP

And here is the `HttpGet`:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
{
   // omitted for brevity...

   // Get the SystemRole models (4 models will be returned)
   model.ApprovingRoles = (await serviceLookup.GetAllRolesAsync(ct)).ToList();
}
```

The SystemRoleModel is simply:

```cs
public class SystemRoleModel
{
    public int    Id     { get; set; }
    public string Name   { get; set; }
    public bool   Active { get; set; }
}
```

The view is composed of `EditorTemplate` as follows:

`Create.cshtml` -> `LetterEditor.cshtml` -> `LetterAttachmentEditor.cshtml`

`Create.cshtml`:

```html
@model LetterModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create RL";
}

@Html.EditorFor(m => m, "LetterEditor", new { ShowApprovers = "1", ShowAttachments = "1", ShowButtons = "1" } )
```

`LetterEditor.cshtml`:

```html
@model LetterModel
    ...
    <div class="panel-body">
        @await Html.PartialAsync("EditorTemplates/LetterAttachmentEditor", new LetterAttachmentUploadViewModel { IsBusy = false, LetterGuid = Model.IdCode.ToString() })
    </div>
    ...
```

And finally, `LetterAttachmentEditor.cshtml`:

```html
@model IList<SystemRoleModel>

@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    var index = i;
    var title = Model[index].Name;

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 mt-3">
            @Html.Label("LetterApprover[" + index + "]", title, new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("LetterApprover[" + index + "]")                  
                  .DataValueField(nameof(SystemUserModel.Id))
                  .DataTextField(nameof(SystemUserModel.EmployeeName))
                  .DataSource(source =>
                  {
                      source.Read(read =>
                      {
                          read.Action("GetUsersByRoleId", "Api", new { roleId = Model[index].Id });
                      }).ServerFiltering(true);
                  })
            )
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <span asp-validation="" class="text-danger"></span>
            @Html.ValidationMessage("LetterApprover[" + index + "]", $"An approver as a {title} is required", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Also, `LetterModel.cs`:

```cs
public class LetterModel
{
    public LetterModel()
    {
        Approvers = new List<LetterApproverModel>();
    }

    // omitted for brevity...

    public IList<SystemRoleModel> ApprovingRoles { get; set; } = new List<SystemRoleModel>();
}
```

Now, with that all out of the way, here is the final rendered dropdown (minus the kendo fluff):

```html
<input id="ApprovingRoles_LetterApprover_0_" name="ApprovingRoles.LetterApprover[0]" required="required" type="text" validationmessage="..." data-role="dropdownlist">
<input id="ApprovingRoles_LetterApprover_1_" name="ApprovingRoles.LetterApprover[1]" required="required" type="text" validationmessage="..." data-role="dropdownlist">
<input id="ApprovingRoles_LetterApprover_2_" name="ApprovingRoles.LetterApprover[2]" required="required" type="text" validationmessage="..." data-role="dropdownlist">
<input id="ApprovingRoles_LetterApprover_3_" name="ApprovingRoles.LetterApprover[3]" required="required" type="text" validationmessage="..." data-role="dropdownlist">
```

**If the user submits this form, I need to receive a list of selected IDs from this array of dropdowns.** I followed an anti-pattern, so I'm hoping the MVC binding will do its magic here. I just need to figure out the name of the model property that I should add of type `List<string>`.

Answer (score 1):

How about try to change the name into `name="LetterApprover[0]"` and `name="LetterApprover[1]"`  and `name="LetterApprover[2]"`  and `name="LetterApprover[3]"` .

Then you could bind  to `List<string> LetterApprover`

**Update**

> Name is auto-appended by MVC due to sub-editor

How about add js codes to change the input name when you submit the form?

I try it like below,  I first add `class="form-control"` to dropdownlist, add `id="save"` to button, then:

```
<script>
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control");
    $('#save').click(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        {              
            items[i].setAttribute("name", "LetterApprover")   
        }        
    });
</script>
```

Then bind to `List<string> LetterApprover`.

Comment: Name is auto-appended by MVC due to sub-editor

Comment: I had the same idea. I was able to take care of the appended prefix but avoided java. I'll post answer

Answer (score 1):

I was able to bind the selected values to a model's property upon submission by modifying the prefix added by the MVC engine:

```html
@using DACRL.Domain.Models.BusinessObjects
@model IList<DACRL.Domain.Models.BusinessObjects.SystemRoleModel>

@{
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "";
}

@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    var index = i;
    var name = "SelectedApprover[" + index + "]";
    var title = Model[index].Name;

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 mt-2">
            @Html.Label(name, title, new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name(name)
                  .Size(ComponentSize.Medium).Rounded(Rounded.Medium).FillMode(FillMode.Outline)
                  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" })
                  .DataValueField(nameof(SystemUserModel.Identifier))
                  .DataTextField(nameof(SystemUserModel.EmployeeName))
                  .OptionLabel("Select " + title).Filter(FilterType.Contains)
                  .DataSource(source =>
                  {
                      source.Read(read =>
                      {
                          read.Action("GetUsersByRoleId", "Api", new { roleId = Model[index].Id, sequence = index + 1 });
                      }).ServerFiltering(true);
                  })
                  .Height(500))
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <span asp-validation="" class="text-danger"></span>
            @Html.ValidationMessage(name, $"An approver as a {title} is required", new { @class = "text-danger  mt-2" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

The line `ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "";` allowed me to control the naming and the binding started workinfg